# FlexJSON - JSONDeserializer String Cannot be caste as Boolean

Tags: json, playframework, flexjson

I am using FlexJson within my play framework application but at the point I am trying to deseralize the json string it throws a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean`:

```
    User user = new JSONDeserializer<User>()
        .use(null, User.class).deserialize(body);
```

Body is the json string passed into the controller using standard jquery/ajax and
where User has the following boolean value declared:

```
    public Boolean isCurrentUser;
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Could you attach the Json string you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: Hi, the json string is : {"user_id":"18","isCurrentUser":"true","title":"mr","description":"description"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Json, Boolean is a type. Your JSon is:

```
{"user_id":"18","isCurrentUser":"true","title":"mr","description":"description"}
```

when it should be:

```
{"user_id":"18","isCurrentUser":true,"title":"mr","description":"description"}
```

Note that *true* is not a String, but a boolean. The parser fails because it finds a String instead of the expected boolean type. Fix the JSon generation to add a boolean, not a String.

Comment: aha, that would make sense. i'll give that a run. Thanks